# Why the time displayed by OS is not the same with the time in UEFI?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, uefi, time

I purchased a new notebook and installed several operating systems on it.  I noticed that if I disabled time synchronization (or I was disconnected from Internet so time sync can't work), the time reported by OS is around last time I shutdown-ed the OS.

I've confirmed that the time in UEFI (by pressing F10 when turning on the notebook) is the correct time.

If I boot OS from ISOs, I can confirm that the time is the correct one (the same one with UEFI).

The time is different only when I boot the OS installed permanently in my harddisk, in this case they're Windows 10 (FastBoot has been disabled) and Ubuntu.  Why they're not using time from UEFI (or BIOS)?  What should I do to make them using time set in UEFI?

Comment: What timezone are the installed OSes?

Comment: Both are in UTC +8.  But I noticed something strange with Ubuntu. `date -u` is supposed to return UTC time but instead it returns local time; and, `date` returns UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Ubuntu assumes RTC is in UTC while Windows assumes RTC is in local time zone.  I ended up configuring Windows to treat RTC in UTC as described in [Does Windows 10 support UTC as BIOS time?](https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time).