# Why does my dual boot machine have diferent times in different times in each OS

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, time, date-time

I currently have have a dual boot setup with Linux Mint Mate 18.2 and Windows 7. What is strange is that during installation I gave both systems the same locale settings (or at least that is what I remember). Now when I log into my mint box the time is set correctly but if I reboot and log into my windows box the time is 5 hours ahead. If I change the time and date settings in windows to the correct time when I reboot and log into my mint box the time is set to 5 hours behind.

What I would like to know is the following:

Why is this happening?

and

How can I fix it so that both systems have the same time and date settings?

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [*Time does not update automatically on Windows 10*](https://superuser.com/q/1267529/432690). I don't know how much Windows 7 differs from 10 in this subject; nor Mint from Ubuntu. Still, my answer there may point you in a right direction.

Comment: One of your time zone settings is probably incorrect. See [Time an hour off when booting between Windows and Fedora](//superuser.com/q/198185) for some troubleshooting tips

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two is most likely that the Linux installation expects the hardware clock to be set to UTC, while Windows expects it to be set to local time.  I would guess your local time is Eastern US.  You can change either OS, but my preference is to tell Windows to conform to *nix standards.  From an elevated command prompt in Windows:

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation" /v RealTimeIsUniversal /d 1 /t REG_DWORD /f
```

Of course, check to be sure the hardware clock IS set to UTC.

Comment: how can I check if the hardware clock is set to UTC? In the BIOS? Or from one of the OS's?