# Incomplete Debian live localisation

Tags: boot, debian, keyboard-layout, livecd, time-zone

I have a live installation of Debian 10.6.0 amd64, burnt on a DVD-RW using imgBurn, for school and I need it to be easily available in italian without much hassle.

If I boot it using its italian localisation support though, while the language is for the most part right (many parts still remain in english) the keyboard is set to US by default and I have to change it to IT everytime, same thing for the timezone, which is set to London and it winds the clock back two hours, which not only affects the clock of the BIOS but my Windows 10 installation's as well (which I now have to synchronize everytime after I'm done with Debian).

I tried downloading the iso again multiple times, switch to a USB installation, disabling Secure Boot or enabling Legacy Mode, but they all give the same result.

What can I do to make it boot with the right keyboard layout and correct timezone at least, everytime I boot it, without having to run command lines each time?

Comment: You can see the instructions for creating a customized CD at https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/Modify/CD and take a look at the README from https://sources.debian.org/src/simple-cdd/0.6.7/README/ which describes the .postinst you can use to add entries to rc.local to set timezone or do whatever else you want. Also perhaps see the Ubuntu way at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: About Windows and timezone: [this](https://superuser.com/a/1268246/432690).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if persistent storage ability works on Debian but you can try install live cd on USB  as described here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/ run, configure your settings and use it on every boot.

Comment: I thought about that, but first I want to be able to do it with a DVD so I don't waste a USB port (it's a laptop so those are always useful) and second it wouldn't really be a solution but more like a workaround.