# Windows timezone/clock resets to UTC each time I switch to ubuntu and back to windows?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-11, time

Well I have disabled all settings regarding "set the time automatically" and "adjust for daylight saving time automatically".

I live in UTC+1. and am running windows 11 as well as ubuntu 22.04.

Yet each time I close down windows, start ubuntu and go back to windows the time is "back" on utc, 2 hours behind the actual time. And until I click "sync now" or set the time manually it stays that way.

This does not happen if I stay in windows between reboots, yet always happens when I boot up linux.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps Windows 11 is as selfish as [Windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1267529/432690). I totally don't know Windows 11, I may be wrong.

Comment: From the duplicate https://superuser.com/a/884311/19943 seems most useful