# when does windows 10 check to automatically set the time?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, time, date-time

I have the same issue as described in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1267529/time-does-not-update-automatically-on-windows-10) question. I have a dual boot with windows 10 and ubuntu and every time I start up windows after having used ubuntu, the displayed time is wrong. This is caused by ubuntu and windows having different opinions on what time zone the system internal clock should use.

When I boot in ubuntu on start up the time is wrong but there is some internal time check and by the time ubuntu has finished starting up the displayed time is correct. That would be my ideal desired behavior under windows as well.

What I currently do is when windows finished starting up, I go to the time options, turn off 'set time automatically' and then turn it on again. Doing that aparently causes windows to actually check the time, notice the discrepancy and then correct it and show the correct time afterwards.

However, if I don't do this manually, windows never seems to automatically check whether the displayed time is correct. So I would like to understand, if you use the option 'set time automatically' does windows ever check if the time is correct? Is there a better way to trigger this check than manually turning this option off and on?

Comment: An alternative duplicate that sets Windows to use UTC from the firmware clock https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time