# Why does Windows 10 show the wrong time on the system clock after a reboot?

Tags: windows-10, date-time, clock

I'm running Windows 10 on my PC.  I have Windows 10 configured to sync to a remote clock.  However, every time I reboot my PC, the clock jumps ahead about 45 minutes and continues to display the wrong time until I manually sync the time to the remote clock again. (By going into Control Panel and turning the "Sync Date and Time" setting off and then back on again)

How can I make sure that Windows 10 always shows the correct time without having to go thru these steps with every reboot?

Comment: Windows uses the time from BIOS/UEFI on boot expecting UTC+0 . The update of the time in Windows afterwards is done scheduled (via service `W32Time`) using a time server (default `time.windows.com`). I guess you can initiate it the same way you mentioned by using the command as admin: `net start w32time && w32tm /resync /force`). After boot your BIOS/UEFI will not be the source of time anymore, but Windows will propagate that back to it. You should check the time in BIOS/UEFI respecting timezones (45 minutes are not unusual). Maybe there is a BIOS/UEFI update available for your mainboard.

Comment: "Windows uses the time from BIOS/UEFI on boot expecting UTC+0" – Does it? I *tried* to get Windows to use UTC because I am multi booting and *every other OS on the planet* uses UTC, but I couldn't get Windows to treat the RTC as UTC. If you search for it, you will find plenty of articles showing how to change Windows to treat the RTC as UTC, but most of them stopped working somewhere around Windows 10 19xx.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - You should edit your question that indicates what you did specifically to setup RTC (UTC) because it certainly is possible, I use it on my personal computer.  There simply isn't enough information to diagnose your problem[.](https://superuser.com/questions/975717/does-windows-10-support-utc-as-bios-time)